# Building an electric resonance machine with no battery for all frequencies at once

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, resonance

Suppose we have some fixed frequency and a electromagnetic wave of that frequency. I want to gather its energy over time to use it as resonance.

In Feynman's lectures, he explains how to do this if we know the frequency (volume 1, chapter 23, under electrical resonance).

This is done by putting in a circuit a capacitor, resistor, and solenoid- as current goes by, it creates a magnetic field in the solenoid which at first fights the current, but once it reaches the peak and the current starts decreasing starts helping the current creating a periodic motion (for details please see the lecture notes- available here https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_23.html ).

This is of course incredibly amazing, and my dream would be to build such a LC circuit that detects electromagnetic fields (say via heating up)- this uses no battery!!!!

The only disadvantage (A major one at that) is that we have to know and calculate the frequency before hand- otherwise the resonance will be very minor.

Is there a way to fix the circuit to handle all frequencies well?
I'm aware of amplifiers you can build with transistors, but these demand a battery which I don't want.

Comment: I think the best you will be able to do is to find a powered device which scans a selected range of frequencies and indicates any signals that it finds within that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed amazing, and the invention which accomplishes this amazing task is called a *radio* which first appeared over 120 years ago.

Specifically, the type of radio you describe is called a *crystal set* which receives electromagnetic radiation through an antenna, processes it, and presents the (very small) resulting AC voltage to an extremely efficient loudspeaker worn in your ear. You can then hear radio broadcasts without the use of batteries or other sources of external power!

DIY crystal radio kits can still be purchased on-line as education aids for people interested in the basics of radio technology.

BUT: Here's the rub, Bub.

The energy density in an electromagnetic wave expanding through space in the *radio frequency* range is tiny unless you are very close to the transmitting station. This means that the amount of useful energy you can gather up out of radio waves to perform work is almost uselessly small unless your antenna were impractically huge, which is why electric power intended to perform useful work is not conveyed from place to place using beams of radio waves.

Note also that if you wish to exploit *resonance* in a *receiver* as a means of magnifying the strength of the collected energy, the receiver must be *tuned* to match the frequency of those incoming radio waves. No resonance means no magnification.

Radios use either variable inductors or variable capacitors to resonate the receiver at a specific frequency.

Comment: Amazing that there is such a radio!
Regarding the resonance, I want one that tunes automatically in some way (not electronically obviously, but in some physical way). So it'd be this magic circuit that manages to get an input of any frequency $v$ and slowly wave back and forth (in any acceptable way, like the LC for example) with frequency $v$ and larger and larger amplitudes. In particular it could serve as a frequency detector (I know you can make one out of a transistor but ewu that requires a battery)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as something that is resonant at all frequencies, by definition. Resonance is when there is a specific frequency where energy transfer is easy, so resonance by definition singles out a particular frequency.

It sounds like what you actually want is not resonance, but simple energy absorption across all frequencies. This would be what is known as a black body absorber. They generally do not require batteries.

Edit: from your comment below it seems that you are looking for a tunable resonance circuit. That can be done simply by adding a [variable capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_capacitor) to the circuit.

Comment: I mean a device that for each fixed frequency develops resonance, but of course if they all come at the same time I expect nothing. So whenever I'd get it close to some WIFI or ac cable I'd see the effect. It's slightly different then what you're saying because in your case it just emits it immediately as heat, while I want there to be a periodic transfer of energy (like the LC circuit) that oscillates along the given input frequency

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer to address this. You should edit your question to clarify. As it is, it seems like you want resonance at all frequencies simultaneously.

Comment: How do you make a variable capacitor that automatically puts the right one? I don't want to manually find out the frequency

Comment: You would need a battery for that.